# Question about Masterpages

Tags: .net, hyperlink, flicker, master-pages, contentplaceholder

Is it possible to target a contentplaceholder in a hyperlink, and make the page flickerfree, as if you were using ajax? I'm a little bad with Visual Studio so i would hate to reprogram the whole page :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are at least 2 ways I can think of that will provide the functionality you are looking for.

1. You can include a script manager in the masterpage file and wrap the contentplaceholder in an update panel
2. Without changing any of the markup, you could include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to implement the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to handle the ajax request.

If you don't want to make changes to the codebehind, I suggest you look at option 2. The code is as simple as including the jQuery file by downloading it or linking to google's [CDN](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js) (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js) and including this in your javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
        alert('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer :) I had my friend trying that script manager and updatepanel .. didnt really seem to work because the hyperlinks didnt "work" nothing happened when you pushed them.

Comment: Well I should've asked you first off what you're trying to do. If you're trying to reload another page inside the contentplaceholder, that's not going to happen (impossible). If you're trying to load another page, either use jQuery or look into using a MultiView control and then switch between the pages. I've also heard of developers switching user control's inside a contentplaceholder to essentially "switch" between pages, not a fan of that method though.

Comment: So you're saying its impossible to reload the content of the contentplaceholder without refreshing the whole page? Thing is .. i have a hyperlink on my masterpage, when i click that .. the contentplaceholder change to my designated url. But i notice a flicker in the logo on top of the page. So i was wondering if it was possible to use it (kinda like frames).

Comment: Masterpages by default, nature of the control, are to postback when redirecting to another .aspx page. Now if you're updating content within the contentplaceholder such as a calendar, labels, etc.. which doesn't navigate away from that page you can use the updatepanel control to handle the server requests.

Comment: You cannot load another page into the contentplaceholder without creative methods (i.e. multiview control, jQuery, user control) and if you are using hyperlinks, you would most likely favor a linkbutton control that will allow you to handle the events in the codebehind.